# JavaFX - object data to TableView

Tags: java, javafx

Have data from db in ResultSet - working good - line `System.out.println(alarm.toString());` prints data OK.

Trying to put the data into TableView - something wrong - line  `System.out.println(data.toString());` - prints last line X NUMBER OF RECORDS, the same in TableView - only last line duplicated a lot.

```
public void setAlarmsTableView(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    private ObservableList<AlarmType> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    columnDeviceIndex.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("deviceIndex"));
    /* ... */
    columnAlarmTime.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("alarmTime"));

    AlarmType alarm = new AlarmType();
    while (rs.next()) {
        alarm.setDeviceIndex(rs.getInt(1));
        /* ... */
        alarm.setAlarmTime(rs.getTimestamp(8));
        alarmsTableView.getItems().add(alarm);
        data.add(alarm);
        System.out.println(alarm.toString());
    }
    alarmsTableView.setItems(data);

    System.out.println(data.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only ever create & modify a single `AlarmType` instance. You need to create one instance per `ResultSet` row however. Also I'm not sure adding the instance to both the `items` list of the `TableView` and the `data` list is neccessary.

```
// AlarmType alarm = new AlarmType();
while (rs.next()) {
    AlarmType alarm = new AlarmType(); // create new instance here
    alarm.setDeviceIndex(rs.getInt(1));
    /* ... */
    alarm.setAlarmTime(rs.getTimestamp(8));
    // alarmsTableView.getItems().add(alarm); // this shouldn't be necessary
    data.add(alarm);
    System.out.println(alarm.toString());
}
alarmsTableView.setItems(data);
```

Comment: That's absolutely right, all `AlarmType`(s) in the Table point to the same object created at the beginning. Nice observation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally did something like that.

```
    AlarmType alarm = new AlarmType();
    while (rs.next()) {
        alarm.setDeviceIndex(rs.getInt(1));
        /* ... */
        alarm.setAlarmTime(rs.getTimestamp(8));
        data.add(new AlarmType(alarm));
    }
    alarmsTableView.setItems(data);
```

The table is full of data, and I'm satisfied learned my fault.
@fabian @Yahya
Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Why create a additional `AlarmType` to hold the data when you're creating a new one from the data anyway? This way your code uses 4 assignments instead of 2: 2 in the setters and 2 in the copy constructor. If you simply create & fill a new instance inside the loop body you only need the 2 assignments for the setters.

Comment: U mean while loop included only `data.add(new AlarmType(rs.getInt(1), /*...*/ ,rs.getTimestamp(8)));`? Yup! U re deadly right! I should have been refacroted code before creating the question